# ZeroMQ on Windows

Tags: c, windows, mingw, zeromq

How am I supposed to install ZeroMQ on Windows7 (x64) using MinGW.
I am not a native speaker and their guide [here](http://zeromq.org/docs:windows-installations) is unclear as well as I downloaded both, Windows Sources and Windows Installer that contains (bin/lib - the compiled sources).

- I added the bin folder in PATH.
- I linked all the libraries.
- I linked the include folder

If I append `-lzmq` to the linker's additional options I get "cannot find -lzmq".
Otherwise I have undefined references to everything.
Trying to compile:

```
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main (void)
{
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    while (1) {
        char buffer [10];
        zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);
        printf ("Received Hello\n");
        sleep (1);          //  Do some 'work'
        zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: At a guess, "cannot find -lzmq" gives a good hint - sounds like you don't need the "-l".

Comment: Great approach. However, now the linker crashes: `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`.

Comment: @Thron: Edit your question and add the full error message of collect2.exe

Comment: It should never be searching for a `-lzmq`, it should be passed `-l zmq` as arguments and then search for `libzmq.lib`.

Comment: `-l zmq` is same as `-lzmq` i.e leads to the error `"Cannot Find -lzmq"`

Comment: @Thron : why you are using MinGW since it is built using Visual Studio ? try Visual studio express if any .. I tried it,it works.

Comment: Please no! I hate Visual Studio. I even hate Windows.. but I have no other choice.

Comment: Yes, the compiler can split the single argument `-lzmq` into the two `-l` (link) and `zmq`. It doesn't for some reason though, most probably because there are arguments `-l -lzmq` where the latter is taken as second argument to the former. That said, if `-l zmq` still gives the same(!) error, then I guess that these two are passed as single argument (e.g. because they are quoted). What is the commandline used for compiling?

Comment: Actually I need to clarify: If passing the arguments `-l` and `-l zmq`  (e.g. by quoting the second) gives an error mentioning that `-lzmq` was not found, then something is seriously broken. I believe that the most important question remains what the *exact* commandline is though, and of course the *exact* error it produces.

Comment: That was the exact error it produces. The args I tried are `-l zmq` and `-lzmq` which does the same. `-zmq` doesn't work at all. But I gave up uppon 0MQ because I saw someone saying that the library is a toy.